# Should I thread tape counter-clockwise on kitchen sink shut off valve?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

Just bought Decor Star TPC11-TB kitchen faucet. In the instructions, it directs you to use Teflon tape on the shut off valve before installing the water supply lines. However, it says to thread in the counter-clockwise direction. Everything I’ve read says clockwise direction, starting from the top, so that you follow the threads. Perhaps the instructions say counter-clockwise because they want you to start from the bottom?[image]

Comment: a compression fitting shouldn't need the tape at all, so i guess it doesn't matter..

Comment: I don’t think they are true compression fittings, there’s no copper ring ferrule

Comment: The point is the thread does not contribute to the seal. There may be some value in the tape in making it easier to disassemble in the future.

Comment: It has a plastic ferrule.

Answer (score 2):

TPFE tape is wound around pipe threads in the same direction that the coupling nut is twisted when tightening. For the illustrated pipe, that would be clockwise. If the pipe were pointing down, but you were looking from above, counterclockwise.

If you wrap it in the direction opposite the nut-tightening direction, the nut will unwind it, it will bunch up and prevent a good seal.

Comment: I agree, with the exception of flammable type fittings that attach ccw I always go CW.+

Comment: @EdBeal Yeah, there are a few reverse thread fitting, but pretty rare.

Comment: I agree that's why I mentioned ccw just in case but with water fittings WTF?